# Java ошибка в алгоритме с коллекцией Set

Tags: java, алгоритм, коллекции

Решал задачу на codeforces. Решил двумя способами, один работает, второй нет.
Не понимаю почему способ решения с Set не работает(входные - выходные данные не показывает которые не прошли). То есть просто ошибка на тесте 5 и все.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://codeforces.com/gym/101784/problem/B

```
int a = sr.nextInt();
    int b = sr.nextInt();
    int c = sr.nextInt();
    int d = sr.nextInt();

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.addAll(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d));

    String res = "ugly";
    if (set.size() == 1) {
        res = "square";
    } else if (set.size() == 2) {
        res = "rectangle";
    }


    System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: используйте hashmap со счетчиком

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы предполагаете, что все входные данные правильны, а тут на этот случай есть в условии вариант "ugly".
Что будет, если на вход подать
1 2 2 2?
1 2 3 4?

Первый вариант проходит по вашим условиям, но ни прямоугольник, ни квадрат по ним не составить.